# Python 2.7 Django 1.9 static files administration error

Tags: python, django

I am trying to solve this for 2 hours now. I tried everything I read every post but I think I am still missing something. My static files are not loading. I am getting this error when I click to static files url path on browsers view-source page. "A server error occurred.  Please contact the administrator." Before this error It was fine in this index page; 127.0.0.1:8000/ But when I try to go on 127.0.0.1:8000/home it was still same index page but it wasn't loading static files because it was looking static files at home/ directory. So I decided to make my static urls dynamic. I though I was not making mistake but Pycharm says unresolved template reference to this;

```
<script src="{% static 'jquery.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'retina-1.1.0.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'jquery.hoverdir.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'jquery.hoverex.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'jquery.prettyPhoto.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'jquery.isotope.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'custom.js' %}"></script>
```

at the begining of the page I used

```
{% load static from staticfiles %}
```

this peace of code. How can ı fix these problems guys I need your help!

Debug = true

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from . import views
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^home/$', views.index, name = 'home'),
    url(r'^$', views.index, name= 'index'),
    url(r'^second/$', views.second, name = 'second'),


]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns +=[
        url(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',
    {'document_root', settings.STATIC_ROOT}
  ),
    ]
```

Settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'basic/static'),
)


STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'assests/')
```

Comment: Are you absolutely certain debug is set to true? You should get an extensive error trace not "A server error occurred. Please contact the administrator."

Comment: Yes I am sure debug is set to true

Comment: Can you remove all but the first URL from your `urlpatterns` and try running your app (keeping the static files url). Just want to make sure another pattern is not conflicting.

Comment: That didn't worked either. and if I am not in home page it gives me error. I think the problem is related to pycharms tip. Unresolved template thing.

Answer (score 0):

Within the django docs for 1.9 the stated way of [serving static files during development](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/static-files/) is to use the following:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Along with the following in your templates:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<img src="{% static "my_app/myexample.jpg" %}" alt="My image"/>
```

Have you tried using this method of serving static files whilst in debug?